# Can't access Qt ui from void function

Tags: c++, qt

My mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
   Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    void test();

private:
Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

My mainwindow.cpp file

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

void MainWindow::test()
{
    ui->textBrowser->append("Hello world");
}
```

<s>QT designer says "ui was not declared in this scope" But i am using it all in the same cpp file.</s>

Edit* Added mainwindow.h for more info.

Comment: It should be `void MainWindow::test()` instead. I.e. your test() function should be the member function of MainWindow class.

Comment: Your mainwindow.cpp still does not read `MainWindow::test()`

Comment: Yes i know i made the change but forgot to add it to the edit, Still getting same error: 'no void MainWindow::test()' member function declared in class 'MainWindow' –

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`test()` must be a member method of class `MainWindow`:

in **mainwindow.cpp**

```
void MainWindow::test()
{
    ui->textBrowser->append("Hello world");
}
```

You must also add in **mainwindow.h**:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

    void test(); //<<

    // ...
};
```

Comment: That fixed the ui error but now i get 'no void MainWindow::test()' member function declared in class 'MainWindow'

Comment: @SkiloSkilo you must add the method in the header file as well

Comment: I still get the same error.

Comment: @SkiloSkilo then you should post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)